# Null reference exception caused by null command parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, .net-4.0

Just a weird exception that I can't get my head around

My code:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Background="{StaticResource ContentBackgroundColour}" BorderThickness="0" Margin="0,3,0,3" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Scenarios}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Padding="0">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="{Binding}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Command="{Binding Path=OpenScenario}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"></Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

And:

```
public ICommand OpenScenario
{
    get { return new RelayCommand(param => _OpenScenario((ManageScenarioModel)param), 
        param => ((ManageScenarioModel)param).IsOpen); }
}

private void _OpenScenario(ManageScenarioModel toOpen)
{
    toOpen.IsOpen = true;
    new ManageScenario(this).Show();
}
```

However the part `param => ((ManageScenarioModel)param).IsOpen)` throws a null reference exception upon start up, can someone please explain why this is?

Comment: Are you asking why you're getting the NullReferenceException or why param is null even though its in a binding?

Comment: Why param is even null in the first place? I mean im using it to create the button and add text, but as a command paramater it is null?

Comment: Binding does not have any specific order of execution, so everything can be null in the beginning based on state of program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because WPF is calling your "CanExecute" expression to determine whether or not the button should be enabled. Apparently your binding is resulting in a null command parameter. You should probably check for a null parameter and return false.

```
param => (param != null && ((ManageScenarioModel)param).IsOpen)
```